# Swift error while starting app, after update to Xcode 10.2 beta 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode10.2

After updating Xcode to 10.2 beta 3, I receive this error while starting app, which will result in crash (app compiles successfully):

> objc[2140]: Swift class extensions and categories on Swift classes are not allowed to have +load methods
>   (lldb)

Do you know what this may be due to?

Comment: Seems that you're not the only one seeing the problem. https://github.com/pmusolino/Wormholy/issues/51

Comment: 1. Quick search for any function names `load` (or containing `load` in the name) and see if renaming solves the issue. 2. List your PodFile/CartFile and isolate the framework causing issue. 3. If everything fails, create a [mcve] and post it on GitHub or BitBucket.

Comment: Same result with the new Xcode release. Did you find a way to detect which classes or extensions violates this new convention? Getting the same result but with no hints at all.

Comment: @ThomasG. Did you find something in the meantime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my case, it is because I added a module which uses Swift to my ReactNative project. In this [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24139) they discussed this bug and there were several solutions.

The official solution is to upgrade RN to 0.59.3+, but it may influence too much for me and I would not to do that for now, so I edited `RCTBridgeModule.h` according to [this commit](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/df7ea6731367df4d24cda316f8b376a26da2e06c?diff=split) as a workaround and it works.

Comment: Wow yeah that did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Some of your dependencies can have +load methods. In my case, there were Firebase and Swinject cocoapods.